# Why i get error "Syntax error in query expression"

Tags: ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I got error i like this "SYNTAX ERROR IN QUERY EXPRESSION _Name= ' ' "
Help me please . what's wrong with my code ?

Try

```
        Connection.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = ("SELECT * from RegistrationTable WHERE _Name = '" & ListBox1.Text & "'")

        command = New OleDbCommand(query, Connection)
        Reader = command.ExecuteScalar
        While Reader.Read
            txtPID.Text = Reader("PatientID")
            txtName.Text = Reader("_Name")
            txtAge.Text = Reader("_Age")
            cmbGender.Text = Reader("_Gender")

        End While
        Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        Connection.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: Is there's anyone who can help me with my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That underscore means that you need square brackets:

```
"SELECT * from RegistrationTable WHERE [_Name] = '" & ListBox1.Text & "'"
```

Comment: Sir why is it my cmbGender , ComboBox1 , ComboBox2  Data i can't display in my textbox ?

Comment: I think you need a new question with more detail.

Comment: What i mean sir is , First i get the data from my access and display it in my listbox but only the name will show in listbox then when you click your name in listbox it will show all the information in textbox . but the problem i can't display the data in my ComboBox Gender , Building and RoomNo .

Comment: I mean that you should post a new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: You must set brackets [ ] in fields starting with underscore ("_"). Try  READ([_Name]) or even READ(Field(1)) - using the number of each field.